# IndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to print data called from MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql

I'm getting a "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0" and I don't even know what is wrong.

I have 4 classes. I get data from two MySQL databases in the first (**ConnectionClass**) and the second one is a main class from which I run and print the result but for some reason it doesn't work. The third and fourth are normal classes.

The first database is called **account** which has a few columns and a foreign key(f_id) from the second database **f**.

My Connection class:

```
package tryout;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ConnectionClass {
    Connection connection;
    public void connect() {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydemo";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "12345";
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<F> getAllFs() {
        connect();
        ArrayList<F> l = new ArrayList<F>();
        String sql="SELECT * FROM f";
        try {
            Statement s = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rSet = s.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rSet.next()) {
                int j=0;
                l.get(j).setF_id(rSet.getInt("f_id"));
                l.get(j).setF_name(rSet.getString("f_name"));
                j++;
            }
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return l;
    }

    public ArrayList<Account> getAllAccounts() {
        connect();
        ArrayList<Account> liste = new ArrayList<Account>();
        String sql="SELECT * FROM account";
        try {
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rs.next()) {
                int i=0;
                liste.get(i).setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
                liste.get(i).setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
                liste.get(i).setFullname(rs.getString("fullname"));
                liste.get(i).setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                liste.get(i).setWebsite(rs.getString("website"));
                liste.get(i).setAge(rs.getInt("age"));
                liste.get(i).setF((F) rs.getObject("f_id"));
                i++;
            }
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return liste;
    }
}
```

My main class:

```
package tryout;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MAIN {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConnectionClass class1 = new ConnectionClass();
        ArrayList<Account> list = new ArrayList<Account>();
        list = class1.getAllAccounts();
        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i).getUsername()+" "+list.get(i).getPassword());
        }
    }
}
```

**Account.java**:

```
package tryout;

public class Account {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String fullname;
    private String email;
    private String website;
    private int age;
    private F f;
    public Account() {
        super();
    }
    public Account(String username, String password, String fullname, String email, String website, int age, F f) {
        super();
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.fullname = fullname;
        this.email = email;
        this.website = website;
        this.age = age;
        this.f = f;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getFullname() {
        return fullname;
    }
    public void setFullname(String fullname) {
        this.fullname = fullname;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getWebsite() {
        return website;
    }
    public void setWebsite(String website) {
        this.website = website;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public F getF() {
        return f;
    }
    public void setF(F f) {
        this.f = f;
    }
}
```

**F.java**:

```
package tryout;

public class F {
    private int f_id;
    private String f_name;
    public F() {
        super();
    }
    public F(int f_id, String f_name) {
        super();
        this.f_id = f_id;
        this.f_name = f_name;
    }
    public int getF_id() {
        return f_id;
    }
    public void setF_id(int f_id) {
        this.f_id = f_id;
    }
    public String getF_name() {
        return f_name;
    }
    public void setF_name(String f_name) {
        this.f_name = f_name;
    }   
}
```

Here are my databases:
[image: pic1]

[image: f2]

I tried changing getAllAccounts to this:

```
public ArrayList<Account> getAllAccounts() {
        connect();
        ArrayList<Account> liste = new ArrayList<Account>();
        ArrayList<F> l2 = new ArrayList<F>();
        //l2 = getAllFs();
        String sql="SELECT * FROM account";
        try {
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rs.next()) {
                Account acc = new Account();
                acc.setAge(rs.getInt("age"));
                acc.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                acc.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
                acc.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
                acc.setFullname(rs.getString("fullname"));
            }
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return liste;
    }
```

and when i run it in the main class nothing shows. The error is gone but nothing is printed in the console.

Comment: Please provide a [example]. You removing all unnecessary code you make it easier for the answerers as well as for yourself to find the cause of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the following lines:

```
ArrayList<F> l = new ArrayList<F>();
String sql="SELECT * FROM f";
try {
    Statement s = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rSet = s.executeQuery(sql);
    while(rSet.next()) {
        int j=0;
        l.get(j).setF_id(rSet.getInt("f_id"));
        l.get(j).setF_name(rSet.getString("f_name"));
        j++;
    }
```

The list has no element but you are using `l.get(j)`.

In order to understand this problem better, run the following code and you will get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println(l.get(0));
    }
}
```

Keeping aside the problem, you are initializing `j` inside while loop which means the incremented value is lost with every iteration. In order to solve the problem, replace

```
while(rSet.next()) {
    int j=0;
    l.get(j).setF_id(rSet.getInt("f_id"));
    l.get(j).setF_name(rSet.getString("f_name"));
    j++;
}
```

with

```
while(rSet.next()) {    
    l.add(rSet.getInt("f_id"));
    l.add(rSet.getString("f_name"));
}
```

Comment: That is not the only snippet where this exception will occur.

Comment: Then how do i add to the arraylist in this case?

Comment: The list is there. It's just empty. You need to fill it with `F`'s

Comment: I tried changing the getAllAccounts you can it now in my question.